# Which of the following are true for singleton classes?

Tags: singleton

dear all sorry for asking basic question.. i still did not understand about singleton.
i still can not figure the answer.

Which of the following are true for singleton classes?
a. Cannot be derived by other classes.
b. Cannot be referred to in a variable.
c. Not more than one instance may exist ever within a runtime.
d. They are thread safes

Answer (score 0):

The answer is C, that's why singleton is "single-ton". It should be very easy if you have put in some effort to google it.